# Can I downgrade macOS to OSX Mavericks if the earliest OS that came with my Mac is macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, downgrade

Google gives me conflicted answers on this.

On Apple's website it says that the earliest os you can restore to is the one that originally shipped with your Mac.

However, I found articles and links like MacWorld that says otherwise. So I thought maybe there are some tricks that can be used to accomplish that goal.

Is this possible ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Mac originally shipped with Mavericks, then yes, you can install Mavericks on it, regardless of whether when you bought it, it had Sierra on it.

Otherwise, no.  Think about it.  If your Mac was released after Mavericks, Mavericks won't have hardware drivers for it.

Answer (score 0):

"Mavericks doesn't know how to run computers from the future." If your Mac is newer than October 2014, it was built after Mavericks was finished.

Depending on why you want to run Mavericks, there may be other solutions, such as using a Virtual machine, or using different applications.